# Disk space required for installation is larger than the one freed after removal: why?

Tags: disk, obs-studio

I installed OBS Studio:

```
sudo apt-get install obs-studio 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-keybinder-3.0 libkeybinder-3.0-0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libfdk-aac0 libluajit-5.1-2 libluajit-5.1-common libxcb-xinerama0
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libfdk-aac0 libluajit-5.1-2 libluajit-5.1-common libxcb-xinerama0 obs-studio
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 3,678 kB of archives.
After this operation, 13.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

I decided to remove it:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove obs-studio Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-keybinder-3.0 libfdk-aac0 libkeybinder-3.0-0 libluajit-5.1-2
  libluajit-5.1-common libxcb-xinerama0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  obs-studio*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 11.6 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

When removing it, I expect **13.0 MB** of disk space to be freed because that is what the installation required, but I got **11.6 MB** disk space freed instead: Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference can be found here:

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libfdk-aac0 libluajit-5.1-2 libluajit-5.1-common libxcb-xinerama0
```

After you uninstall `obs-studio`, these packages should be available to remove using `apt-get autoremove` if no other packages depend on them.

You could also run:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge obs-studio libfdk-aac0 libluajit-5.1-2 libluajit-5.1-common libxcb-xinerama0
```

and you should get the original size directly.

Comment: I think you are right. I run `autoremove` and 1 477 KB more were freed

Answer (score 4):

Because not everything gets removed. Notice that the package requires couple libraries installed among which `libluajit-5.1-2`. During uninstallation only the package itself is removed, and you’re prompted to use `autoremove` to get rid of unused other packages. Re-read the uninstallation prompt again. Config files also may not get removed. For full removal sometimes `--purge` option is advised.

As for why that's done so, I can only guess it's a protective feature, as various software relies on libraries and APIs,  so promoting system admin to remove them manually is a sanity check that it's exactly what they want. Or in other words, avoiding breaking things just in case.

Comment: Thank you for the "deeper" explanation (you got my upvote)